# Logrotate --debug is pulling status from alternate locations

Tags: logrotate

Here is my config file:

```
/path/to/somelog.log {
    daily
    copytruncate
    compress
    delaycompress
    nocreate
    missingok
    rotate 7
    dateext
    dateyesterday
    dateformat _%Y-%m-%d-%H-%i-%s
}
```

For testing, I am attempting to run some tests of logrotate using the following command:

```
$ sudo logrotate --state /dev/null --log ./logrotate.log /etc/logrotate.d/my-config
```

But when I run it, I get entries like this:

```
considering log /path/to/somelog.log
Creating new state
  Now: 2023-07-21 15:11
  Last rotated at 2023-07-21 15:00
  log does not need rotating (log has been already rotated)
```

Which is strange, because

**How does it know that I last ran a test at 15:00 if I told it to use /dev/null for its state file?**

(I have also run tests after 15:00, but apparently somewhere besides /var/lib/logrotate/status it stored the test I did at 15:00)

Looking at the state file, nothing has been saved:

```
$ cat /var/lib/logrotate/status
logrotate state -- version 2
$
```

And I have told it to use /dev/null for the state file anyway, so it shouldn't matter what's in the global state file. I can't find anything in the docs about alternate places that it stores state information, so I'm at a loss as to how to get it to ignore the tests so I can run these tests in rapid succession.